# Какие хостинги контейнеров с мгновенным деплоем вы знаете?

Tags: docker, hosting, облако

Какие хостинги контейнеров с мгновенным деплоем вы знаете?

Azure/Container instances - **~15 сек** до старта

Alibaba/Elastic Container Instance - **~35 сек** до старта

Может вы знаете быстрее?

Comment: А какое вам нужно время на старт? Используем AWS ECS/ECR время старта зависит у нас от цепочки деплоя в CI/CD, где с момента оформления релиза до нового образа в проде уходит до 7минут. Время старта это не особо важный показатель, обычно в облачных сервисах запускается до нескольких копий контейнера, если новый контейнер не стартует то продолжает работать стабильный. Это не заметно для пользователя.

Comment: Идеально - 5 секунд и менее из заранее приготовленного образа. В моём случае мощности выделяются по запросу клиента и ожидание неприемлемо.

Comment: AWS Lambda не пробовали? и на чем у вас приложение, стар приложения в докере никто не отменит, особенно если это Node.js или Python.